# Get day of year and generate number

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am generating
a date sequence between 2020 and 2022. I write the query in Redshift.
From this sequence I extract days, weeks, etc.
I try to get the day of the year but I get the day of the month.
I also try to generate a sequence of numbers starting from a given number (like 2020001, 2020002, ...,2021001, 2021001...2021365) but it doesn't work either.
The problem is that I can't find anything similar.  Can anyone help me with the query?

```
SELECT date '2014-12-31' + INTERVAL yydd,
       DATE_PART(day, yydd) day,
       DATE_PART(dayofweek, yydd) day_week_number,
       DATE_PART(day, yydd) day_month_number,
       DATE_PART(QUARTER, yydd) quarter_number,
 FROM  generate_series(1, (date '2031-01-01' - date '2015-01-01')) interval;
```

Comment: `select extract(doy from current_date); 333`. It is spelled out here [Extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

Comment: yes, it's day of month. But I need day of year (1, 2...365)

Comment: And I showed you how.

Comment: Sorry!) doy--  I didn't know about it! Thank you :)

Comment: Be aware that generate_series() is a leader node only function in Redshift and cannot be used in conjunction with data table information or in creating a table on Redshift.  To make this more general you will need to change to a recursive cte.

Answer (score 0):

Working code shown below

Per the [documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Dateparts_for_datetime_functions.html) the appropriate string in date_part function to generate day of year can be 'dayofyear', 'doy', 'dy', or 'yearday'

```
SELECT
  intrvl.*
, DATEADD(day, intrvl,'2000-01-01'::date)::date yydd
, DATE_PART('doy', yydd) AS day_of_year
, DATE_PART(dayofweek, yydd) AS day_of_week_number
, DATE_PART(day, yydd) AS day_of_month_number
, DATE_PART(QUARTER, yydd) AS quarter_number
FROM  generate_series(0,365*10) intrvl
```